# Missing Download PDF Button in Orders for Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, order, pdf

I'm not sure what happened, but the "Download PDF" button that is on the orders in the CMS is missing. I thought maybe the order PDF template file or path was missing but both of those are there. Is there a true/false statement somewhere I might have erased? I can't find anything on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Download PDF button will show if the `OrderModel` that gets passed to the template's `getPdfUrl()` method returns a URL.

You can see the logic it uses in `commerce/models/Commerce_OrderModel.php`, `function getPdfUrl()`.

It gets the `orderPdfPath` Commerce setting, then checks if that template exists on the front-end templates folder.

My guess is you've got something messed up with the path to that template somewhere.